# How to extract data(time) from .txt file?

Tags: python-2.7

I have .txt file, from txt file i want all the timings to check the performance. How to get the all times in to new list?

below is my .txt file:

```
03-21 12:09:34.123 application open
03-21 12:09:35.122 date 
03-21 12:09:36.124 completed
03-21 12:09:37.125 None
```

Below is what i tried:

```
def memory(self):
    self.empty = []
    time_x = []
    heap_y = [0,20,40,60,80,100,120]
    pattren =re.compile(r'^(([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)|24:00)$')
    with open("C:\\Sakurai_Robot\\testlogs\\logcat_105010176.log", "r") as gummi:
        for i in gummi.readlines():
            if pattren.search(i) !=None:
                self.empty.append(i.rstrip('\n'))

        print self.empty
```

I want only time like:

```
12:09:34
12:09:35
12:09:36
12:09:37
```

But i am not able to get.is there any way we will get all the times into new list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it completely without using regular expression, too:

```py
timestamps = []
with open("C:\\Sakurai_Robot\\testlogs\\logcat_105010176.log", "r") as gummi:
    for i in gummi.readlines():
        timestamps.append(i.split(" ")[1].split(".")[0])

print timestamps
```

Answer (score 0):

This code here should work through your problem.

```
    import re
    output = []
    p = re.compile('\d\d:\d\d:\d\d')
    with open("path", "r") as fle:
        for i in fle.readlines():
            lst = p.findall(p)
            for match in lst:
                output.append(match)

    for a in output:
        print(a)
```

When run against your input, the output is as follows:

```
    12:09:34
    12:09:35
    12:09:36
    12:09:37
```